# Remove items in a list based on a list of substrings in another list in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to subset a list of strings based on another list of substrings. I want to remove strings in list1 if the string includes a substring in list2.

```
list1 = ['lunch time', 'sandwich shop', 'starts at noon','grocery store']

list2 = ['lunch','noon']
```

The output I want:

```
output = ['sandwich shop','grocery store']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re


list1 = ['lunch time', 'sandwich shop', 'starts at noon','grocery store']
list2 = ['lunch','noon']
pattern = re.compile(r"|".join(list2))
print([i for i in list1 if not pattern.search(i)])
```

**Output:**

```
['sandwich shop', 'grocery store']
```

Comment: This was so fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to iterate on the copy of `list1` and remove the string from it if it contains a substring from `list2`

```
list1 = ['lunch time', 'sandwich shop', 'starts at noon','grocery store']

list2 = ['lunch','noon']

#Iterate on copy of list1
for item1 in list1[:]:
    #If substring is present, remove string from list
    for item2 in list2:
        if item2 in item1:
            list1.remove(item1)

print(list1)
```

Another approach is to find the matching substrings, and then subtract that result with the actual list

```
list1 = ['lunch time', 'sandwich shop', 'starts at noon','grocery store']

list2 = ['lunch','noon']

#List of strings where the substrings are contained
result = [item1 for item1 in list1 for item2 in list2 if item2 in item1 ]

#List of strings where the substrings are not contained, found by set difference between original list and the list above
print(list(set(list1) - set(result)))
```

The output will be the same in both cases as below

```
['grocery store', 'sandwich shop']
```

Answer (score 1):

So many different ways to do this. Here is my approach (may not be the best).

```
list1 = ['lunch time', 'sandwich shop', 'starts at noon','grocery store']
list2 = ['lunch','noon']


list3 = [x for x in list1 if len(set(list2) & set(x.split())) == 0]


print(list3)
```

Gives you:

```
['sandwich shop', 'grocery store']
```

What is happening?

1. Loop through the first list items.
2. Convert the item to an array of words using `split()`.
3. Convert that array and list2 to a set.
4. Do a set union to find which are similar.
5. Count how many were similar using `len()`.
6. If nothing was similar, then add the item from list1 to list3.
7. Repeat until no more items.